# Reebok — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Где ставить ударение в слове Reebok?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

На первом слоге (ри́бок), как в английском, так и в русском варианте. И это не аббревиатура (только первая буква заглавная при любом написании; русский вариант - в кавычках как название фирмы). Слово обозначает один из видов южноафриканской антилопы и в данном написании (reebok) взято из бурского языка (ныне именуемого африкаанс) с письменностью в латинице; в английском для этого вида животного (Pelea capreolus) оно пишется иначе: rhebok.

Answer (score 1):

Из Википедии: Reebok (МФА: /ˈriːbɒk/, **произносится — ри́бок)** — международная компания по производству спортивной одежды и аксессуаров. Штаб-квартира расположена в пригороде Бостона Кэнтоне (штат Массачусетс). В настоящее время является дочерним подразделением компании Adidas.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reebok